# Using ThreadPool for processing files

Tags: .net, vb.net, multithreading, visual-studio, threadpool

Currently we have a server where files are being saved at a rate of about 10,000 files per day (500 an hour).

My program is already sucessfully parsing those files and throwing the relevant information into a database. The problem is, my single threaded application is no where near able to keep up with the pace and is really falling behind.

I want to try and create a threadpool of 3-5 threads to see if that will help keep up.

The application looks into a file folder and grabs all the file names like this:

```
      For Each newfile As String In Directory.GetFiles(fileLoc)
      Next
```

What I would like to do is to assign each file to a thread in the thread pool based on if the thread is active or not, something like this:

```
          For Each newfile As String In Directory.GetFiles(fileLoc)
                   If Not (Thread1.IsAlive) Then
                        Thread1 = New Threading.Thread(Sub() dowork(arg1, arg2))
                   ElseIf Not (Thread2.IsAlive) Then
                        Thread2 = New Threading.Thread(Sub() dowork(arg1, arg2))
                   ElseIf Not (Thread3.IsAlive) Then
                        Thread3 = New Threading.Thread(Sub() dowork(arg1, arg2))
                   End If
            Next
```

I was browsing the forums and I came accross one tutorial using

```
 System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(Sub() dowork(arg1, arg2))
```

Not sure if this is what i am looking for, but I didnt see a way to set the number of threads active in the pool (3-5).

So my question is - How can I go through a list of files, and assign the files to an open/available thread?

Any and all help is greatly appreciated, thank you -Z

*EDIT*

```
    For Each newfile As String In Directory.GetFiles(fileLoc).AsParallel.WithDegreeOfParallelism(10)
        theWorker(newfile)
    Next
```

Comment: Check out https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.setmaxthreads(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to managed any pools yourself.

```
Directory.GetFiles(fileLoc)
.AsParallel().WithMaxDOP(3)
.ForEach(path => dowork(path, arg2));
```

That's it. Determine the optimal degree of parallelism experimentally.

Comment: .ForEach does not seem to be an option? Also thank you for the help, this solution seems insanely simple

Comment: I meant `ForAll`. That's different from `foreach`. It's a PLINQ method. I always confuse these names.

Comment: Can you take a look at the above edit and tell me if it does the same thing?

Comment: That's a serial for each loop. That is not parallel.

Comment: Directory.GetFiles(fileLoc).AsParallel.WithDegreeOfParallelism(4).ForAll(Sub() theWorker(<thisfilename>))   .... so in this example, how would i fill the "thisfilename" with the name of the for each?

Comment: See the example code in the answer. The path is the argument to the delegate passed into ForAll. Try to understand how this works instead of slapping code strings together...

Comment: I was struggle with the "path =>" .... in vb.net it's .ForAll(Sub(path) theWorker(path)) ... Thank you...